# Slider bar with text values

Tags: asp.net, ajax, slider

I'm doing a permissions screen that could use a slider bar- for each section of the site, I want to be able to give users permissions easily, using a horizontal slider bar that has text values defining the different levels of permissions, meaning what they can do in each section of the site, increasing in permissions to include abilities like reading data, writing, deleting items, adding them etc. Every level includes the previous levels, so a slider bar seems the logical choice to show that's what's going on.

Unfortunately, looking around, the only slider bar with good ASP integration (this is part of an ASP web form) is the AJAX one, SliderExtender, but that only uses numbers as values. Is there a way to use text values as the labels for this control, or is there another (free) one that I can use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I've tried the AJAX SliderExtender- that was when I came upon the problem. I haven't found anything else that has a reasonable chance of working. Most of the ones I've found are purely client-side, with little server-side interaction. I found one that might have worked, but I would have had to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use numeric values and handle convert the numbers to text values in your code?

- 1 = Admin
- 2 = Power User
- 3 = User
- 4 = Other User

Hope this helps